# How do I get all permutations in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Say I want to get:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
etc
```

I'm to do `(til 3) (,\:) til 3` but this doesn't seem to do it, giving me a type error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cross](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cross/) keyword is what you are looking for

```
q)(til 3) cross til 3
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

The solution to your original problem without using a keyword is:

```
q)raze ((til 3),/:\:) til 3
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```